# How do I update my gfortran compiler?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, fortran

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with gfortran 4.8.4 and I need the version 4.9.X to compile some things...
I ran the command `sudo apt-get gfortran-4.9` and then `gfortran --version`, but I see that I have 4.8.4 installed. What could I do?

Comment: Get manually from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gfortran-4.9)  or update your sources.list at least xenial.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't overwrite the symlink of the default compiler version when you install additional versions from the repository - you either need to modify the symlink (manually or via the `update-alternatives` mechanism), or call the newer version explicitly i.e. `gfortran-4.9`. If whatever you're building respects it, it may be sufficient to simply set an appropriate environment variable e.g. `make "FC=/usr/bin/gfortran-4.9"` or `export FC=/usr/bin/gfortran-4.9; make`

Comment: @steeldriver You are right my friend! Can you write it as an asnwer please?